# Ctrl-tab in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, keyboard-shortcuts, intellij-idea

Can I configure IntelliJ on Windows to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> for switching between files?

Googling finds [this old thread](http://www.jetbrains.net/devnet/thread/943) that says "no".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can't get a pop-up, but you can switch between open tabs with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd>, and you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> to get a list of recently opened files, which is almost the same thing.

EDIT: (In response to comment) Oh, if that is what, it is just a question of changing the KeyMap. You go to `File -> Settings` and under there you have a keymap option. You will have to create a new KeyMap (can't change the default) by clicking copy, and then look in the other section for "Select Next Tab in multi-editor file" and change/add the keymap you want. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> is legit - it is just defaulted to switching between splits.

EDIT 2: (In response to second comment) The function you are looking for in IDEA (at least as close as it gets) is Go Back, which is in the other group of the key map as well. That being said, you said you were looking for how it works in firefox (don't know about Visual Studio) and "Select Next Tab" is the firefox behavior.

Comment: I was hoping to keep the key binding I'm used to from Firefox, Visual Studio, ...

Comment: This is not 100% correct - CTRL-Tab finds the last tab that you opened, while "Select Next Tab" finds the next tab in the arbitrary tab order of the editor.

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried downloading and installing the TabSwitch plugin? It will allow you to cycle through your open editors and display them in a pop-up window when you hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>. This default keymapping is easy enough to change to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> in the Keymap IDE Settings.

Answer (score 8):

If you are looking for the functionality you normally get by clicking
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> with web browsers, you can change "Select Next Tab" in keymaps settings:

**Window > Editor Tabs > Select Next Tab**

[image: Settings > Keymaps > Window > Editor Tabs > Select Next Tab]

Comment: you can set this to react to Ctrl+Tab and Ctrl+Shift+Tab in Intellij on Mac, by going to `Preferences | Keymap`, search for "Select Next Tab", then double click the entry to  "Add new shortcut", and then click the "+" sign in the first entry field, and choose `Set ^⇥`

Answer (score 5):

Ensure to disable option "Support screen readers" in File | Settings | Appearance & Behaviour | Appearance :[image]

This option blocks these shortcuts

Source: [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-284234/CtrlTab-and-CtrlShiftTab-doesnt-switch-editor-tabs)

Answer (score 4):

You can't enter 'Ctrl+Tab' using a keyboard, but you can select it from the drop-down menu:

[image: Ctrl+Tab]

Answer (score 3):

TabSwitch is certainly the answer to this question.  Without doing this, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> to pop up the list of recent files and navigate there.  So jumping to the most recent file would be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

It already works that way. You don't need to configure IntelliJ to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> for switching between files, it comes installed to accomplish this.

Comment: Ripper234 asked how to switch through tabs in the same order they appear like in Firefox or Visual Studio. Ctrl+Tab switches through tabs in the same order they've been opened not showed. Every last opened tab is stacked on top of the previous ones. Ctrl+Tab simply iterates the stack of the last opened tabs.